# How to configure the Drawer Navigation button when not using the start as the top-level navigation?

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, android-navigation

I'm using the navigation graph to navigate and have a start screen (splash fragment) as the first fragment that is shown. The issue is that when I go to the main fragment/screen the top navigation button shows back instead of the drawer icon.
How can we get control over this? What are some options. How can I change the start destination? (if possible)

> When the user is at a top-level destination, the Navigation button
> becomes a drawer icon  if the destination uses a DrawerLayout. If the
> destination doesn't use a DrawerLayout, the Navigation button is
> hidden. When the user is on any other destination, the Navigation
> button appears as an Up button . **To configure the Navigation button
> using only the start destination as the top-level destination, create
> an AppBarConfiguration object, and pass in the corresponding
> navigation graph, as shown below:**

**Example Code**

My issue is that the back button is still present when navigating to next_fragment. It should show the menu/hamburger icon.

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

private lateinit var drawerLayout: DrawerLayout
private lateinit var appBarConfiguration : AppBarConfiguration

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

    val binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView<ActivityMainBinding>(this, R.layout.activity_main)
    drawerLayout = binding.drawerLayout

    val navController = this.findNavController(R.id.mainNavigationHostFragment)
    NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController)

    appBarConfiguration = AppBarConfiguration(setOf(R.id.nextFragment), drawerLayout) 
    NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(binding.mainNavigationDrawerView, navController)

    val navigationHeader = binding.mainNavigationDrawerView.getHeaderView(0)
    val iconButton = navigationHeader.findViewById<ImageButton>(R.id.main_nav_icon_button)
    

}

override fun onSupportNavigateUp(): Boolean {

    val navController = this.findNavController(R.id.mainNavigationHostFragment)
    return NavigationUI.navigateUp(navController, appBarConfiguration)
}
```

}

Comment: As per the [Principles of Navigation](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-principles#fixed_start_destination), you shouldn't be using a splash screen as your start destination. `NavigationUI` assumes you're actually following the Principles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of passing `Navigation Graph` to `AppbarConfiguration`, pass the **id** of the Fragment that should show the `HamBurger icon`, that way when the particular **Fragment** is shown, it shows **home/hamburger** icon instead of **back** icon.

**That is**

`val appBarConfiguration = AppBarConfiguration(setOf(R.id.FAGMENT_THAT_SHOULD_SHOW_HOME_ICON), DRAWER_LAYOUT)`

***Update***

**Instead of**

```
val navController = this.findNavController(R.id.mainNavigationHostFragment)

NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController) 

 appBarConfiguration = AppBarConfiguration(setOf(R.id.nextFragment), drawerLayout) 
    NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(binding.mainNavigationDrawerView, navController)

val navigationHeader = binding.mainNavigationDrawerView.getHeaderView(0)
  val iconButton = navigationHeader.findViewById<ImageButton>(R.id.main_nav_icon_button)
```

**Just**

```
val navController = this.findNavController(R.id.mainNavigationHostFragment)

appBarConfiguration = AppBarConfiguration(setOf(R.id.nextFragment), drawerLayout) 
    

NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController, appBarConfiguration);
```

Comment: Hi, I actually tried this and what happens is that the functionality works but the button icon is still a back arrow @Debarshi Bhattacharjee

Comment: Are you using **Drawer** or it's just that you wanna show the hamburger icon??

Comment: Im using drawer, your solution works as I have tried it but the icon doesn't change from back icon to hamburger icon.

Comment: Then you need to pass the **DrawerLayout**  as a second argument to **AppbarConfiguration**.

Comment: Yes, Im actually doing that. I added my example code that is part of MainActivity in my question. This is the line right ? AppBarConfiguration(setOf(R.id.nextFragment), drawerLayout)

Comment: And now ```setupWithNavController(navController, appBarConfiguration)```

Comment: Thanks, this worked but now there is a back button on the main fragment the first fragment. But I guess this can be considered a solution.